# Get (p5) canvas element when it has loaded

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have two scripts, in one of them I have an animation on a p5 canvas, and on another script I do some operation on it.

Script A - p5 animation:

```
function setup() {
  let canvas = createCanvas(640, 480);
  canvas.id("vizCanvas");
  // ...

}

function draw() {
 // animation ...
}
```

Script B - doing something with the animation:

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById('vizCanvas');
doSomethingWithMyCanvas(myCanvas)

function doSomethingWithMyCanvas(canvas){
    console.log('hello', canvas)
}
```

view.ejs (~= index.html):

```
<head>
  <script src="src/scriptA.js" defer></script>
  <script src="src/scriptB.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

The problem is that `myCanvas` is null. When I use the dev console and type `test = document.getElementById('vizCanvas')` it successfully references it though. I suppose this means that Script B is trying to fetch `vizCanvas` before it has been created. I would think that the `defer` keywords in the tag doesn't allow the scripts to be executed until the window has loaded, but that doesn't really work.

I tried to wrap Script B in a `window.onload` event, like this:

Script B (revision 1)

```
window.onload = ()=>{
  const myCanvas = document.getElementById('vizCanvas');
  doSomethingWithMyCanvas(myCanvas)

  function doSomethingWithMyCanvas(canvas){
      console.log('hello', canvas)
  }

}
```

But when this happens, the p5 animations don't actually work anymore. In fact, if I just change Script B to:

Script B (revision 2)

```
window.onload = () => {
  console.log("hi")
}
```

the p5 animations will not play! That said, `update()` in p5 seems to be running and everything, I just don't see anything.

So my question is: how do I fetch the p5 canvas element once it has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setup()` function doesn't run right away. It runs after p5 sets itself up and then starts calling functions like `setup()` and `draw()`. So you're trying to access the canvas before the `setup()` function has run.

There are a couple ways to get around this:

1. Call a function from `setup()` after you create the canvas. That function can be defined in your other script file if you want.
2. Use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) which gives you a bit more control over when p5.js runs.

I would personally go with option 1, but it depends on your context and what you're trying to do.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the suggestion I would've never discovered this on my own